# joining array of strings + a separator

Tags: java, arrays, string, join

java noob here...

This is driving me nuts because I know it's something so simple but I have been working on this for 30 mins...

this is from codefights:

For arguments = ["Code", "Fight", "On", "!"] and separator = "/", the output should be
myConcat(arguments, separator) = "Code/Fight/On/!/".

my code:

```
String myConcat(String[] arguments, String separator) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= arguments.length; i++){
        String output = arguments[0] + separator;
    }
    return output;
}
```

error: file.java on line 5: error: cannot find symbol
    return output;
           ^
  symbol:   variable output
  location: class _runfniek
1 error

any tips would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Add the appropriate language tag. In any case, the current compile-tme error is unrelated to the concatenation operator or arrays or even the act of joining. Start with the actual problem and then widen as it works better than shotgunning everything. Hint: what is the *scope* of `output`? Why might this variable ("symbol") *not* be accessible outside the for-loop, as written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, StringBuilder is prefered than + operation.

Second, it is a mistake to define String output in the loop body which does not save the value actually.

Third, need consider the border, i.e. no separator should be appended for the last element of the argument array.

Fourth, it is `i < arguments.length`, not `i <= arguments.length`

```
String myConcat(String[] arguments, String separator) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        output.append(arguments[i]);
        if(i < arguments.length-1){ 
             output.append(separator);
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of my errors. I read and understood your code. I did find one thing though.

your code currently would not add the separator at the very end. so instead of "Code/Fight/On/!/", it would output "Code/Fight/On/!" I fixed this by getting rid of the -1 at the arguments.length-1

Answer (score 1):

```
String output = arguments[0] + separator;
```

arguments[0] -> arguments[i]
and the String output var must be defined out the for{}

the error tip is very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the String `output` only exists within the for statement, it needs to be created outside of it, ideally using stringbuilder:

```
    String myConcat(String[] arguments, String separator){
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            output.append(arguments[i]);
            output.append(separator);
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

You seem to want the trailing separator, if unneeded you could remove it with an if statement